# How to get QuickTime Player 7 to save its export settings?

Tags: macos, mac, quicktime, applescript

I'm trying to get QuickTime Player 7 on Mac OS X 10.6.4 to save its export settings so I can batch convert some MKV movies to M4V (MPEG-4).

I've already exported a movie using the settings I want.  The settings I want to save are for an export of a "Movie to MPEG-4".

When I run this AppleScript to save the settings:

```
tell application "QuickTime Player 7"
    activate
    tell document 1
        save export settings for QuickTime movie to file "Macintosh HD:Test.set"
    end tell
end tell
```

I get this error: "QuickTime Player 7 got an error: An error of type -2107 has occurred."

I can not find any reference to this error type on the net.

From what I can tell, using AppleScript is the only way to instruct QuickTime 7 to save its export settings.

Is there an easier way of doing this?  Is there something wrong with my AppleScript?

Answer (score 0):

From my answer on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034730/applescript-quicktime-export-to-image-sequence-problem/1084703#1084703)

Yes, you do have to use AppleScript in order to export the settings file.

I don't personally get the error -2107 running your script, but it doesn't save the file for me.

Try:

```
set file2save to (choose file name default location (path to desktop) default name "setting.qtes")

tell application "QuickTime Player 7"
    tell first document
        save export settings for QuickTime movie to file2save
    end tell
end tell
```

While you can export the document using that settings file:

```
tell application "QuickTime Player 7"
    #Change this path to wherever the .qtes file is
    set settings_file to "Macintosh HD:setting.qtes"
    set movie2save to (choose file name default location (path to desktop) default name "QuickTime.mov")
    export document 1 to movie2save as QuickTime movie using settings alias settings_file
end tell
```

Comment: moved from edit by anonymous user:  The `-2107` happens if you do not have a "most recently used" settings, I found after I performed a save after visiting the options dialog (even if I did not change anything), I then had a "most recently used" settings, and the export of the settings was successful.